# Unable to insert an image in a custom object via Apex code

Tags: lightning-web-components

I am working in Lightning web components.

**HTML**

```xml
<template>
<lightning:card>
   <lightning-file-upload
               label="Attach receipt"
               name="fileUploader"
               accept={acceptedFormats}
               record-id={recordId}
             onuploadfinished={handleUploadFinished}>
               
       </lightning-file-upload>
   <lightning-button label="Save" variant="brand" onclick={handleClick}></lightning-button>
</lightning:card>
</template>
```

**JS**

```js
import { LightningElement , wire, track, api} from 'lwc';
export default class PriceScreen extends LightningElement {
 selectedIds;
 
    @api recordId;
    get acceptedFormats() {
        return ['.pdf', '.png','.jpg','.jpeg'];
    }
  
  handleUploadFinished(event) {
        // Get the list of uploaded files
        const uploadedFiles = event.detail.files;
        
        for(let i = 0; i < uploadedFiles.length; i++) {
            this.selectedIds = uploadedFiles[i].Id;
        }
      
    }
}


  handleClick(event) {
 
 
    newClient({ photo:this.selectedIds})
      

   .then(result => {
    const evt = new ShowToastEvent({
        title: 'Saved succesfully',
        variant: 'success',
    });
    this.dispatchEvent(evt);
    
    })
  .catch(error => {
        this.error = error;
       
   });
 
 
 }
```

**APEX**

```java
@AuraEnabled(cacheable = false)
public static Boolean newClient(Id photo ){
 
   Client__c client = new Client__c();
   client.Photo__c = photo;

   try {
    insert client;
    return true;
       
   } catch (Exception e) {
       throw new AuraHandledException('exceptionText' + e.getMessage());
     
   }
  
}
```

'Client' is a custom object, having a rich text area field 'Photo'. I am uploading the photo using lightning:file:upload. But the uploaded image is not getting saved into the custom object. Is there any mistake in my code? Actually, I don't know how to save an image into a custom object via apex code.

Answer (score 0):

You need a proper HTML fragment, such as:

```
client.Photo__c = '<img src="'+imageSource+'" />';
```

Where imageSource would be derived from the file URL:

```
String imageSource = Url.getFileFieldURL(photo, 'VersionData');
```

Additional work may be necessary, but this information should get you started.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get you. Could you please explain it in detail?

Comment: I am new using LWC

Comment: @AthiraVenugopal This has nothing to with LWC. You need to fix your Apex code.

Comment: What is this 'VersionData?

Comment: @AthiraVenugopal A field on ContentVersion, which is what you create when you upload a file.

Comment: String imageSource = Url.getFileFieldURL(photo, 'VersionData'); What is this 'photo'?  Actually I got the version data.

Comment: String imageSource = Url.getFileFieldURL(photo, EncodingUtil.base64Decode(base64Data));  //error in this line, unknown label 'photo'

Comment: @AthiraVenugopal `photo` was the ID you passed in in the method parameter. The VersionData is the field from which to extract the data.

Comment: Could you please show an example, how to get the 'VersionData' of an uploaded image? Because there is an error: Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void getFileFieldURL(String, Blob) from the type System.Url

Comment: if you know, please show it, its urgent for me to complete this.